# Change color of text ( foreground ) in Elevated Button

Tags: flutter, dart, styles, themes, foreground

Using Flutter, I set ElevatedButton theme in the style.dart with this.

```
ThemeData appTheme(BuildContext context) {
  const fontFamilyFallBack = ['Lexend', 'NotoSans'];
  return ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.green,
        onPrimary: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(
        fontFamilyFallback: fontFamilyFallBack,
      ),
      subtitle1: TextStyle(
        fontFamilyFallback: fontFamilyFallBack,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
      bodyText1: TextStyle(
        fontFamilyFallback: fontFamilyFallBack,
        fontSize: 14,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

But still the color of the foreground which is my text still does not change to `White` as the value of `onPrimary` whereas the color of the background is appliable.

```
ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(
            'Tap go to second page',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
          ),
          onPressed: () => context.router.pushNamed('/error'),
        )),
```

[image: described image]

I have also tried *ButtonStyle* one, but I still get the same result.

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Its working here. If thats the case, will you mind checking whether you have set the appTheme to the theme property in the MaterialApp?

Comment: Yea surely I have set that property cus the `backgroundColor` property still work as in the image

Comment: You can please show us `MaterialApp` widget?

Comment: Sure `MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: appTheme(context),
      routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
    )`    Sorry for this messy code

Comment: If it is a public a repository then, I want to check it once by myself. Can I?

Comment: Its my company repository, cant public its then.

Comment: Btw, why are you taking a `BuildContext` as argument in the `appTheme()` function?

Comment: Cus `ThemeData` method need `context` as argument to apply `Theme` globally

Comment: Can you show me how you are using that `BuildContext`? I guess it might be the problem if you are using `Theme.of(context)`

Comment: I extract method `ThemeData appTheme(BuildContext context)` to another file like this

Comment: Yes I can see that, but can you try to test without using the `BuildContext`?

Answer (score 0):

You pass `ButtonStyle` to the `style` property like this:

```dart
ThemeData(
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Sorry for not mention earlier but I have tried this and get the same result.

Comment: Its working here. If thats the case, will you mind checking whether you have set the `appTheme` to the `theme` property in the `MaterialApp`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: Text(
        'Tap go to second page',
        style: 
Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.copyWith(color:Colors.green),
      ),
      onPressed: () => context.router.pushNamed('/error'),
    )),
```

Comment: Surely this will work but I need to specify my whole `elevatedButtonTheme` globally for future adjustment. Thanks btw